# store path of photo in db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting to add a logo to a user profile, and I am doing this through two models (contractor and logo) and a one-to-one relationship.

I am getting the logo to upload properly to uploads/logos, but I am failing to store anything in my logo table.

I am note sure what I am overlooking, any suggestions:

my user controller:  ContractorController.php  *note: I am using dropzone.js in my view

```
public function logo_upload($id){

  $input = Input::all();
  $rules = array(
      'file' => 'image|max:3000',
  );

  $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

  if ($validation->fails())
  {
    return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
  }
    $file = Input::file('file');
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/logos';
    //$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $filename = str_random(12).".{$extension}";
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();

    if( $upload_success ) {
       return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
       return Response::json('error', 400);
    }

    if( $upload_success ) {
         $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
        $contractor->logo->name = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();
        $contractor->logo->contractor_id = $contractor;
        $contractor->save();
    }
}
```

My conractor model:

```
 function logo() {
    return $this->hasOne('Logo', 'contractror_id');
}
```

My logo model:

```
public function contractor() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Contractor', 'contractor_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just swap the following code:

```
if( $upload_success ) {
   return Response::json('success', 200);
} else {
   return Response::json('error', 400);
}

// This code is out of reach if return occurs
if( $upload_success ) {
    $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
    $contractor->logo->name = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();
    $contractor->logo->contractor_id = $contractor;
    $contractor->save();
}
```

To something like following:

```
if( $upload_success ) {
    $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
    $logo = new Logo(array('name' => Input::file('file')->getRealPath()));
    $contractor->logo()->save($logo);
    return Response::json('success', 200);
} else {
   return Response::json('error', 400);
}
```

It's not reaching the code for saving the `path` in database because before that you are returning from the script so the code after the `return` is not getting executed. Btw, I just copied the code from your question and swapped it with small modification so not sure about your saving code whether it's working or not.

**Update:** Updated the code to save related model. Check how to  save related models on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models).

Comment: I switched to your suggestion, which makes perfect sense.  I must have an error in my save code, since the site returns a "trying to get property of non-object" error

Comment: @retrograde, Add `protected $guarded = array()` in your `Logo` model.

Comment: I have switched the code and am now receiving this error: {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function logo() on a non-object","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/contractorSherpa\/app\/controllers\/ContractorController.php","line":181}}

Comment: Then your `$contractor = Contractor::find($id);` is returning nothin, try to debug if you get a `Contractor` model by `dd($contractor)` after the `::find()` and make sure the `$id` is right and you have a record with that `id`.

Comment: I am not sure what the output is supposed to be with dd($contractor), but the upload works, when I add it and remove everything below the Contractor::find($id). The id is already present on the view page through <h1><span>{{ $contractor->name }}</span></h1> preceding the form and the record exists and is editable through my other forms.

Comment: `$contractor = Contractor::find($id); dd($contractor)` should contain the `Contractor` model object according to `id` or null if not found.

Comment: $sheikh yep that is the problem.

Comment: I added a hidden field into the form with the contractor_id passed in and referenced it in the controller.  Works great now.   Thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

After you follow Heera instructions, you should also review how you are trying to store anything to your logo table. It should be something like this:

```
$contractor = Contractor::find($id);
$logo = new Logo(array('name' => Input::file('file')->getRealPath()));
$contractor->logo()->save($logo);
```

Comment: I switched to your code, which looked to me like it would work, but I got this error:      {"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\MassAssignmentException","message":"name","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/contractorSherpa\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Eloquent\/Model.php","line":344}}